# Using variables in Azure logic app inline code

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

i use a logic app to define a variable named "symbol". Now i want to use the value of the variable in a later part of my logic app but the dynamic contents doesn't show my variable. How must the code look like so that I can use the variable in the inlinecode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code), "this capability **doesn't support variables**, loops, and iteration indexes".

Sometimes, [`Compose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations) actions can be used instead of variables. The output of a `Compose` action can be used in inline code.